# Relation between estimator's consistency and biasedness

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

I have two quick question:

> If an estimator is consistent, does that imply it is unbiased?
>
> If an estimator is biased, does that imply it is not consistent?

we know that consistency means when $bias^2+variance=0$

so, consistent means both are zero. because both are positive number. But this is for all case or not. Any type of suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consistency is an asymptotic property, which roughly asks, as our sample becomes large, does our estimator become accurate. Bias on the other hand, is a not an asymptotic property. The bias tells us, given a sample, how off our estimator is in expectation. There are consistent estimators that are biased and unbiased estimators that are not consistent.

*Based on your question, I assume you are asking about mean square consistency, i.e. if $\theta$ is the true parameter, and $\hat{\theta}$ is an estimator, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} E( (\theta-\hat{\theta})^2)\to 0$ (which happens if the squared-bias and variance of the estimator converge to 0). There is another, more commonly used notion of consistency, which is that $p\lim \hat{\theta} \to \theta$. It can be shown that neither of these are the same as unbiasedness, in fact the example below shows it for either.*

Since this is an asymptotic property, it does not imply unbiasedness. For instance, if a sample $X_1 \cdot X_n$ are drawn independently from $N(\theta,1)$, then the estimator $\hat{\theta_n} =\frac{\sum X_n}{n}+1/n$ is a consistent estimator for $\theta$. The first term converges to $\theta$ by the law of large numbers, and the second term converges to 0, which means that asymptotically, the bias and the variance goes to 0 (since it converges to a constant). But, $\hat{\theta_n}$ is not unbiased, $E(\hat{\theta_n})=\theta + \frac{1}{n}$.

A less "artificial" example would be the sample variance. If estimated using $\frac{1}{n} \sum(X-\bar{X})^2$ is a biased but consistent estimator of variance.